# AJAX call returning data but failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I've been trying to make an ajax call to retrieve some data from a database but i don't know why is returning an error.

there's the code

```
$('#afegir_pagament').submit(function() {
                        var import_pagament = $('#import_pagament').val();
                        var id_reserva = $('#id_reserva_hidden').val();
                        url = "afegir_pagament.php";
                        data = {import: import_pagament, id_reserva: id_reserva};
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            dataType: 'application/json',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: data,
                            complete: function(xhr, statusText) {
                                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                            },
                            success: function(responseText) {
                                $('#pag_import_pagat_propietari').val(responseText.total);
                            },
                            error: function(req, status, err) {
                                alert('Error');
                            }

                        });
                        return false;
                    });
```

console.log(xhr.responseText) returns {"total":"230.00"}

ERROR: no conversion from text to application/json

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Check your network tab in the Chrome/Firefox dev tools. Check what the HTTP response and requests look like.

Comment: Just `JSON.parse(responseText)`.

Comment: It looks good. HTML: {"total":"230"} | JSON total    "230"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"application/json" is not a valid value for the dataType property. Change it to "json".

See [here (comment #7)](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8216):

> Thanks for the report, but this is not a jQuery bug. application/json is not a valid value for the dataType property.

Answer (score 0):

Just change application/json to datatype :"json" and exactly what you trying to do inside the 
success function ..if you trying to display this value in your text field just try this..

```
$("#pag_import_pagat_propietari").attr("#yourid",responseText.total);
```